# hive explode list from json-string

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hadoop, hive

I have table with jsons:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_JSON (
  json_body string
 );
```

Json has structure:

```
{ obj1: { fields ... },  obj2: [array] }
```

I want to select all elements from array, but I can't.

For example, I can get all fields from first object:

```
SELECT f.fields...
    FROM (
        SELECT q1.obj1, q1.obj2
        FROM TABLE_JSON jt
        LATERAL VIEW JSON_TUPLE(jt.json_body, 'obj1', 'obj2') q1 AS obj1, obj2
      ) as json_table2
    LATERAL VIEW JSON_TUPLE(TABLE_JSON.obj1, 'fields...') f AS fields...;
```

But with array this method doesnt work.

I've tried to use

```
...
    LATERAL VIEW explode(json_table2.obj2) adTable AS arr;
```

[hive explode doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView)

But obj2 - string with array. How to transform string-json to array and explode it?

Comment: is the size of array fixed across rows?

Answer (score 3):

The json_split UDF from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) can convert a JSON array to a Hive List, and then you can explode that.

See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201406.mbox/%3CCAO78EnLgSrrUY3Ad_ZWS9zWNKLQRwS9jXrqEE869FhUNiWgCXA@mail.gmail.com%3E and https://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Hive-JSON SerDe to read the data from JSON.

Refer: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an optimal solution but can help unblock you. For a JSON object which looks like below

```
'{"obj1":"field1","obj2":["a1","a2","a3"]}'
```

this query can help you obtain all items of array into individual columns given that the size of the array is constant across all rows.

```
    SELECT split(results,",")[0] AS arrayItem1,
       split(results,",")[1] AS arrayItem2,
       regexp_replace(split(results,",")[2], "[\\]|}]", "") AS arrayItem3
    FROM
       (SELECT split(translate(get_json_object(TABLE_JSON.json_body,'$.obj2'), '"\\[|]|\""',''), "},") AS r
       FROM TABLE_JSON) t1 LATERAL VIEW explode(r) rr AS results
```

It produces the result which looks like this

```
arrayitem1| arrayitem2| arrayitem3
a1        | a2        | a3
```

You can scale it to any number of array size on a condition that size is constant across the table.